# Bad permissions for mapped region

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

I get an error when trying to run the following function:

```
   char* reverseInPlace(char* src)
{
    //no need to alloc or free memory
    int i=0;
    int size=mystrlen(src);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        int j=size-i-1;

        if(i<j)
        {
            char temp;
            printf("Interchange start %d:%c with %d:%c",i,src[i],j,src[j]);
            temp=src[i];
            src[i]=src[j];//error occurs here
            src[j]=temp;
            printf("Interchange complete %d:%c and %d:%c",i,src[i],j,src[j]);
        }   
    }
    return src; 
}
```

I call this code like this:

```
char* rev2=reverseInPlace("BeforeSunrise");
printf("The reversed string is %s\n",rev2);
```

The error looks like this:

```
Interchange start 0:B with 12:e
Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x401165
```

Why does this error occur?

Comment: BTW that question ^^ is the first Google hit. **Literally the first one.** Don't be lazy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are passing a constant string to your function.

String literals are of type `char [N + 1]` (where `N` is the length of the array) in C, but modifying them results in undefined behavior. Your compiler should have already issued a warning at that point.

If you wish to modify it then you have to create a copy:

```
char str[] = "BeforeSunrise";
char* rev2=reverseInPlace(str);
```

Comment: No, string literals are neither const nor pointers. They are non-const arrays, but modifying them results in undefined behavior. Furthermore, the assertion that "[they] are placed during runtime in read-only process memory" may or may not be true, and it is completely irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: @H2CO3 isn't it true for even `const` qualified variables in C, that they are not true `const` in the C++ sense and result in undefined behavior when trying to change their value?

Comment: @ajay What do you mean by that "they are not true const in the C++ sense"? This has nothing to do with C++, it's a C question. And in C, `const` qualified objects are `const` qualified, and not modifiable. That's all. (Yes, modifying them is UB.)

Answer (score 2):

It's because you try to modify a string literal, which is a *constant* array, i.e. it's read-only.

Comment: It's read-only, but not constant (assuming you meant "`const`-qualified" by constant), unfortunately. (This is one of the cases where C++ got it right and C got it wrong.)

Comment: @H2CO3 so C++ is like 'Don't even try to change a const!' where as C is like 'Well go ahead I don't care' and later 'told ya! treat it as a const!'

Comment: @ajay No. It's that string literals are not `const`-qualified in C. Explicitly modifying a `const` object in C is a hard compiler error.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks for clarifying and dispelling this wrong idea I had. I just checked it and got a flat compile error. Always learning. One step at a time :)

Comment: @ajay lesson learned: don't generalize. "String literals behave in a particular way" doesn't mean that "everything in C behaves in that particular way".